# Copy and paste RESULTS of a file search

Tags: windows, command-line

In order for me to get the results of a file search in a readable format, I use the following command line in a command prompt:

```
dir *.* /s > myResultList.txt
```

I then open that list in Excel, use fixed width format to get rid of all the stuff I don't want and then I have my list.

Seems like a lot to do for something so simple.

Does anyone out there have any recommendations for something that would work better than this?

Comment: Question will be better phrased by including the information you DO want to extract from the DIR results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard to understand what exactly you're aiming for, but you can get a plain list of files by including the `/b` switch to `dir`:

```
dir /s /b *>foo.txt
```

If you have requirements for the exact format of the output, then perhaps a `for` loop might be more appropriate:

```
(for /r %x in (*) do (@echo."%x";%~tx;%~zx))>foo.csv
```

This would output a CSV file with the file names, their modification date and time and the file size, which you can easily open in Excel.

If you want a fixed-width format of custom columns—that's ... <strike>a little</strike> much more complex and I won't provide that here.

Answer (score 1):

Using '[Powershell](http://www.microsoft.com/powershell)' and the '[Powershell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com/)' you will get access to the `get-clipboard` and `out-clipboard` commands, which can be used as explained [here](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/10/17/manipulating-the-clipboard-with-powershell/).

Another candidate: '[nircmd.exe](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)' with the `clipboard` subcommand. Finally, try '[clip.exe](http://www.labnol.org/software/tutorials/copy-dos-command-line-output-clipboard-clip-exe/2506/)' to pipe output to the clipboard on the command line.

**UPDATE**:

Since Vista, there seems to be a `clip.exe` in `C:\Windows\system32`.

Answer (score 0):

[`find`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/findutils.htm) allows you to specify various criteria for searching for files, and lets you generate output using various formatting options.

Comment: i think his real problem is not the search/find but how to transfer the result of (basically any commandline operation) into excel/word etc.